# Find the last 3 digits of $2015^{18}+2015^{19}+2015^{20}+...+2015^{2018}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Obvious I would find the sum of the numbers mod 100, but how would I handle this when the powers are so large? Calculating one already seemds ridiculous.

Comment: You need to work $\pmod {1000}$, not $100$.  But it isn't so bad.  $2015\equiv 15\pmod {1000}$ and except for some small exponents, $15^n$ is periodic $\pmod {1000}$.

Comment: Please remember that you can choose an aswer among the given is the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2):

Note that the last 3 digit for $2015^2$ are the same for $15^2=225$ and then they repeat periodically

- $15^3=...375$
- $15^4=...625$
- $15^5=...375$
- ...

then

$$2015^{18}+2015^{19}+2015^{20}+…+2015^{2018}\equiv1001\cdot625+1000\cdot 375 \pmod{1000}\equiv \Large{625}$$

Comment: I got $625$ by the same method...aren't there more even powered terms than odd powered terms?

Comment: @lulu yes, 625 is the correct answer, I checked it from Wolfram.

Comment: @ArsenBerk  Thanks for checking.

Comment: @lulu ops of course I've exchanged the value in the last step, thanks I fix!

Comment: No problem.  +1.  (note:  you accidentally typed $675$ instead of $625$ ).

Comment: @lulu opsssssssss I can't write the good aswer here :)

Comment: It's that kind of problem.  Took me 4 tries to count the number of even terms correctly.

Comment: I count correctly from 18 to 2018 the even are of course 1001, it was just a typo between the values for the reminders :)

Answer (score 1):

Consider that since $2015$ to any power will have a final digit of $5$, since the last digit of $2015$ is $5$. (You can check the first few of these using a calculator)

Also consider that you have an even number of elements. Anything ending in $5$ multiplied by an even number will have a last digit of $0$. ($5 \times 2 = 10$, $15 \times 3 = 45$, $25 \times 4 = 100$). You can therefore conclude that the last digit will be a $0$.

You should be able to make conclusions about the next two digits using a similar method of generalizations.

Comment: Note;  there are an odd number of terms in the sum.

Answer (score 1):

Modulo $1000$,  $15^3=15^5$; so, for $k\geq 3$, $$15^k=\begin{cases}15^3,&\ k\ \text{ odd}\\ \ \\ 15^4,&\ k\ \text{ even}\end{cases}$$
Then, still modulo $1000$, 
$$
S=\sum_{k=0}^{2000} 2015^{18+k}=\sum_{k=0}^{2000} 2015^{k+2}
=15^{2}+1000\times15^3+1000\times 15^4=15^2=625. 
$$
So the last three digits are `625`.

Answer (score 1):

We need to work modulo $1000 = 2^3 5^3$.  Since $2015$ is divisible by $5$, the sum  is congruent to $0$ modulo $5^3.$  Reducing the sum modulo $2^3$ yields

$$1 -1 + 1 - 1 +\cdots -1+1 \equiv 1 \pmod{8},$$

since $2015 \equiv 15 \equiv -1 \pmod{8}$. So you need to use Chinese remainder theorem to solve the system

$$x\equiv 0 \pmod{125}$$
$$x\equiv 1 \pmod{8}$$

which yields $x \equiv 625 \pmod{1000}.$

Comment: @Goddard, How can we apply CRT if one of the residue is $0$?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Why is a $0$ residue a problem?  Usually, at the end of the problem, the monkeys are able to divide the coconuts evenly.

Answer (score 0):

As $2015\equiv15\pmod{1000},$ we need $\displaystyle\sum_{r=18}^{2018}15^r\pmod{1000}$

As $(15^n,1000)=5^3$ for $n\ge3,$

let us find  $\displaystyle  S=\sum_{r=18-3}^{2018-3}15^r\pmod{1000/5^3}$

As $\displaystyle15\equiv-1\pmod8,S\equiv\sum_{r=18-3}^{2018-3}(-1)^r\equiv-1\pmod8$

$\displaystyle15^3S\equiv15^3\cdot-1\pmod{15^3\cdot8}\equiv-15^3\pmod{8\cdot5^3}$ as $5^3|15^3$

Now $-15^3=-225\cdot15=-3375\equiv-375\equiv1000-375\pmod{1000}$ as $S>0$