# find the last digit - should i use $\mod 10$ to show this?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences

When it is said to find the last digit of a number and the number is given in $a^b$ or $a^{b^c}$ format it is easy to find using either basic congruency or Fermat's little theorem or Euler's phi-function. But in the exam question is of this type   $$1!+2!+....+99!$$ and I did it in this way

$1!=1\equiv 1$ $mod$ $10$
$2!=2 \equiv 2$ $mod$ $10$
$3!=6 \equiv 6$ $mod$ $10$
$4!=24 \equiv 4$ $mod$ $10$, and
$n!=n.(n-1).(n-2)....4.3.2.1 \equiv 0$ $mod$ $10$ for $n \geq5$

Hence adding up all the factorials and the remainders we get

$1!+2!+3!+4!+n! \equiv 1+2+6+4 \equiv 13 \equiv 3$ $mod$ $10$

Hence, $$1!+2!+....+99! \equiv 3\mod10$$

My question is should I use $\mod10$ here because no other conditions are given to solve it. The remainder we find that is the digit in unitary place of a number, I think.   Any help is appreciated.

Comment: see laso here for a similiar slightly more challenging problem https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2672805/find-the-last-3-digits-of-201518201519201520-20152018/2672841#2672841

Comment: the problem you referred is great and nicely solved.

Comment: I think you can find many of them here on MSE!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes of course even if in this case is very simply as you noticed since

$$1!+2!+....+99!= 1!+2!+3!+4!+10\cdot N = 3 +10\cdot M$$

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are doing fine. To find the last digit, use $\mod{10}$

In general, to find the last $k$ digits, use $\mod{10^k}$.

Comment: $789 \equiv 89 \pmod{10^2}$.

Comment: @thevbmthelord:  $\bmod 10^n$ gets the last $n$ digits.  If you want the digit in the tens place you need to take $\bmod 10^2$ and then extract the tens digit, say by dividing by $10$ and ignoring the remainder.